# install4j Windows Edition 7.0.9 - an error in Install file step

Tags: install4j

install4j Windows Edition 7.0.9(build7273)
I run the exe file and get an error from "Install files" step
this step copy my files to $ folder (temporary folder)

Install file: D:\RT.Server.Service.Pack.7.1.1\$\rtserver.install4j\i4jinst.dll; size: 171008 bytes; exists: false
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.InstallFilesAction [ID 53416]: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:428)

windows server2012 R2

-

-

Comment: Does D:\RT.Server.Service.Pack.7.1.1\$\rtserver.install4j exist at that point?

Comment: Yes. The path exists and all the files copied.

Comment: D:\RT.Server.Service.Pack.7.1.1\$\rtserver.install4j\i4jinst.dll is copied, too? Do you have anti-virus software with "real-timr protection" running?

Comment: Yes. The  i4jinst.dll is copied and I uninstalled  anti-virus before and this is not the issue.

Comment: Does this also happen if you install into a directory that does not contain the $ sign?